# Used to vs. To be used to

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs, present-participles

> I used to playing tennis.
>
> I was used to playing tennis.

Are these sentences correct? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Visit this website(http://www.mayfairschool.co.uk/use-to-and-use-to-doing.html).

Comment: I was used to play tennis - is incorrect (it means that smb. used you like a tool to play tennis...which is impossible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I **used to** live in London.

Here **used to** is a modal verb meaning *used to say that something happened continuously or frequently during a period in the past.* <sub>**source** - Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary</sub>

It has no other form, and as it's a modal verb it's followed by an infinitive form of verb without *to*.

So the correct pattern is - Subject + **used to** + (infinitive form of) verb (without *to*)

Modal verb **can** has a past form. It's **could**. But in this case only **used to**, there is no present form. No other form.

So it's wrong to write this -

> - I use to live in London (INCORRECT)

Similarly the following sentence is also wrong -

> - I used to living in London (INCORRECT) [*I can do it*. This is a correct sentence. But if you use *doing* in place of *do* there, will not it be incorrect? Same thing here.]

In your second example -

> I didn’t think I could ever **get used to** living in a big city after living in the country.

Here **used** is the adjective. It means **accustomed**. The correct pattern is - be/get + **used to** + *verb-ing*

> Don’t worry—you’ll soon **get used to** his sense of humour.

**N.B.** - Many people will object writing **get used to + infinitive form of verb without *to***, mainly because that is an obsolete pattern/usage. Though you can find similar constructions in older texts, it's very rare in recent texts. <sub>Information based on OED</sub>